# Over-ridden Constructors

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign members of one class within the constructor of another class. But I receive error that "can't assign because members are private."
Code is something like this :

```
Class Class1 {
    private:
        string name;
        string city;
}

Class Class2 {
    private: 
        string id;
        string age;

            Class1 var; //Class1 type variable defined.

    Public:    
        Class2(){   // Now I will define constructor.

        }
        Class2(Class1&, string name1, string city1) {
            var.name = name1;     // error reported , class1 private member
            var.city = city1;     // error reported , class1 private member
        }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `Class2` doesn't have the power to mess with a private member of a `Class1`. The fact that the `Class1` in question happens to be a member of the `Class2` is irrelevant. (Great class names, by the way.)

Comment: Not only is `Class Class1` not C++, but even if it were it would be a terrible naming scheme. Can anyone look at this and understand in one sitting what's going on? Try to pick simple, short, *distinguishable* names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign value to the private members of class1 from class2.

I would create a constructor in class 1 that would initialize the variables name and city:

```
Class1(string n, string c)
{
 name=n;
 city=c;
}
```

Then in class2 constructor , I would call that constructor as follows:

```
Class2(Class1&, string name1, string city1) 
{
   var = Class1(name1,city1);        
}
```

Thats the best I could suggest based on your code snippet.

Comment: I don't know why my code is still no working. Gives the error that argumetn 1 needed, 2 provided...something like that

Comment: Sindhu .. Now If I want to make a function that has to return Class1 variables of Class2. Which parameters I would return so that there is no error of private members

Comment: You have to use getters in class 1 to get the values of private variables:

Comment: You could also change the scope of city and name to "protected", then you could use them in sub-class, then you could assign value and get value directly using variable name...

Comment: I added one more question, give me upvote if my answers helped you :)

Comment: Sindhu I need 15 reputations to do so...I am just a beginner

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get some of the simple problems out of the way. You're using `Class Class1 { ... }` to define a class, when it should be `class Class1 { ... };`. That is, the keyword is `class` and you need to end the definition with a semicolon. In addition, the first parameter of your `Class2` constructor is of type `Class1&` but you're not even using it. Any `Class1` you pass in here will just be wasted.

In your example, `var` is of type `Class1` and is a *member* of `Class2`. This doesn't give `Class2` any special privilages to be able access `Class1`s private members. They are completely private.

In your title, you say you are overriding constructors. Overriding only applies to class inheritance. A class that inherits from another may override its member functions. So right now, it's unclear if you want `Class1` to be the base class or a member of `Class2`.

If inheritance is what you're looking for, you should change your declaration of `Class2` to `class Class2 : public Class1 { ... };`. This means that `Class2` inherits from `Class1`. You will still not be able to access the members of `Class1` though, because they are private. To make them available to your derived class, you need to make them either `protected` or `public` - the former being preferred.

```
class Class1 {
  protected:
    Class1(string name, string city) : name(name), city(city) { }
    string name;
    string city;
};

class Class2 : public Class1 {
  private: 
    string id;
    string age;

  public:
    Class2(string name1, string city1)
      : Class1(name1, city1)
    { }
};
```

If you want composition instead - that is, `Class1` is a member of `Class2` - then you need to give `Class2` some way to set the members of `Class1`. At the moment, its members are private so you can't do anything. You *could* make them `public`, but that would be *highly discouraged*. One better way to do it is to provide public `setName` and `setCity` functions in `Class1` that allow `Class2` to do:

```
var.setName(name1);
var.setCity(city1);
```

Better yet, because I tend to think making setters for the sake of it is pretty bad design, you should give `Class` a constructor that sets the name and city and initialise `var` in `Class1`'s initializer list:

```
class Class1 {
  public:
    Class1(const string& name, const string& city)
      : name(name), city(city)
    { }
  private:
    string name;
    string city;
};

class Class2 {
  private: 
    string id;
    string age;
    Class1 var;

  public:
    Class2(string name1, string city1)
      : var(name1, city1)
    { }
};
```

Comment: Great ...Just One thing. What does this syntax implies: ": name(name), city(city)"..???

Comment: That is an [initialization list](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/). It initializers the members `name` and `city` with the constructor arguments `name` and `city`. They just happen to be named the same here but look at `Class2` for a better example. There we initialize `var` with arguments `name1` and `city1`.

Answer (score 1):

As said in another answer, you could use constructor to initialize the variables of class 1:

Now to get the values, you should do something like this in class 1:

```
public string getName()
{
 return name;
}

public string getCity()
{
 return city;
}
```

Add these two functions to your class1:
Then in class2, you could get the values of city by call them:

```
var.getCity();
```

or

```
var.getName();
```

These would gain you access to class1 variables in class2.

Answer (score 0):

As your compiler tells you name and city are private to Class1 one and thus can be accessed only from within class two.

The only way to use name and city would be either to add a Ctor to Class1 that takes name and city as arguments and then to provide (public) methods (getters/ setters) to get those values and to set those values.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set a private member variable outside of that class.

Try protected (if you are using inheritance), public (the easy way out), or (best yet!) **create setter and getter functions**, and make those functions public.

Simply (overly simplified actually) you want ALL variables to be private and SOME functions to be public. Each variable needs a setter and getter function if it is private and you want to call it outside the class.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/70937/

Comment: "Each variable needs a setter and getter function if they are private" Oh now that's a huge generalisation.

Comment: In addition it is worth noticing the fact that you don't neet a getter setter for sure. If both classes are tighly coupled then a friend directive can work too.

Comment: Kos: Updated to be more specific. Jack: Since we are talking to a beginner, I think tried to keep it simple. Thanks both.

Comment: @jack   But Class1 type var is now the private member of Class2.Why can't I assign it values in pulic.
And I can't change private to pulblic.
See this:
Declare a private Class1 type variable in the Class2 class.
Finally add another constructor that also takes in an Class1. This constructor should look something like
Class1::Class1(Class1 , string,string,int);
PS: To initialize the private Class1 variable in constructor you can use the copy constructor

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you cannot access private members of a type from another (non-friend) type. Ever.

Also you're two-phase initialising your `var` member, where it seems utterly unnecessary. Write a proper constructor

```
Class1::Class1(std::string const& name, std::string const& city)
: name(name), city(city) {
}
```

and invoke it from `Class2`:

```
// what is that first parameter for?
Class2(Class1&, string name, string city)
: var(name,city) {
}
```

You can make `Class1`'s constructor public, or you can make it private and explicitly befriend `Class2`.

Comment: I still don't get. Your syntax is too strange for me. Can you please use simple syntax with public and private classes declare
I did nt get : name(name), city(city){}

Comment: That's the member initialisation part of the constructor. It's pretty common syntax.